# Exploding multipart feature if different parts are over certain distance using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, editing, multipart, explode

I'm using ArcMap 10.4 and working with parcel data. I'm trying to come up with a way to combine parcels owned by the same person that are close to each other, but leave parcels that are further out as their own feature. In the attached picture I'd want the northern cluster of selected parcels to be merged, but leave the southern one on its own. I've dissolved the data set by owner and was wondering if there's a tool that would be similar to the explode multipart feature that would be more like "explode if parts are more than x meters away."

Anything like that, or am I stuck manually combining or separating parcels?

[image]

Comment: An alternative to this could possible be dissolving by field only if the features are touching or within x number of meters

Comment: Try to dissolve with option create multipart un ticked or use multipart to single part tool.